# Choosing SMTP or SendMail in a Rails app in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to follow this tutorial http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html and at the bottom it gives configuration options for SendMail and SMTP.  Neither one works for me so far :)

Which one is more commonly used and what are the considerations of trying either one of those?

Also, in the tutorials, they provide examples of configurations in this format:

```
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>'
```

In my application, what are these referring to?  I don't really have passwords?  And once I do figure them out, should I keep the brackets or no?

Also, what is the difference in http host and smtp host? How do I figure out the domain of my smtp host?  My general domain is localhost:3000 - should I just use that?

```
 :address => "domain-of-smtp-host.com"
 :domain => "domain-of-sender.com",
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is a protocol that SendMail implements.

What you need is an SMTP server for which you have valid credentials, be it your own or some remote service (ie google mail).

Then just enter those credentials and you should be done.

I guess you don't have an SMTP server set up locally, so for testing purposes you can use your xyz Email provider.

And no, remove the brackets once you found out what credentials you want to enter there.

Comment: Thanks, so do people just use google's smtp credentials to send mail from their own servers?  How is that usually done?

Comment: @GeekedOut: No, that's not what people usually do. Are you running an application that needs to send out emails to the world? In that case, you should set up your own SMTP server or let someone (hoster, cloud provider) do that for you. If on the other hand you just want to test your ruby/rails skills and maybe send an email to yourself, there's nothing wrong with using the SMTP server that someone has setup for you already. That could be the provider that you are using for your regular email traffic. You will need to find out under what name that provider's SMTP host can be reached.

Comment: but if I use ubuntu, I am sure it comes with some smtp configs that are easy to set up or are already set up, right?

Comment: @GeekedOut ok, is that smtp server running? And if so, does it require credentials? If it is running and does not require credentials, then your host would be localhost and the port should be 25 but where would it deliver the emails to? Cannot tell from here.